# how to get My phone number in Android 2.2

Tags: android, phone-number, sim-card

I'm programming Apps in Android 2.2. 
I tried to get my phone number in Android but can't...
As below , this is my code for get phone number : ( device for Apps - SamSung Galaxy Plus )

```
public static String getMyPhoneNumber(Context aContext){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) aContext
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}

String phone = getMyPhoneNumber(getApplicationContext());// return "" in here
```

I have added the "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" in Androidmanifest.xml
but when I run apps, the Phone is EMPTY...

I don't know why , although I get the " g`etSimSerialNumber(), getSimOperatorName(),getSimOperator()`,..." is OK !

The method "`getLine1Number()`" always return "" value. 
If you known that , please help me !

Comment: can you see your phone number in the device under - settings>about phone >status>My phone number .. ? if you cant , the android OS doesn't know your phone number therefore not able to give it to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465835/how-to-obtain-phone-number-in-android check this thread also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using getSubscriberId() which is the IMSI for the phone.

Comment: I had fixed it :)... Thanks all

Comment: nice that you fixed your issue..but your question was to get Phone number that means "Contact no" right..!! and the answer suggest IMSI.. So I would suggest to edit your Question to IMSI from Phone Number.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you number is visible in `Settings->About phone->State->Phone number` if not you will not be able probably to get it.

It will not display You phone number until it is written on your mobile SIM,so try to change SIM so when you change the SIM and if phone number is written over there it will show the phone number.

Comment: when I change to another SIM card , I get phone number is OK. Why have difference between SIM type .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a phone no of your Mobile phone where the sim card is inserted, like +92xxxxxx,+42xxxxxxx,+1xxxxxx this type then just copy this code in your apps.

```
TelephonyManager phn_mngr = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String PhnNo= phn_mngr.getLine1Number();
```